How to move emails from cpanel to ISPConfig
I need to transfer all email mailboxes from my VPS to ISPConfig webserver. I have roundcube webmail on cpanel and same on ISPConfig.
Some mailboxes were over 5GB of emails. How to safely transfer all emails. I have created matching email mailboxes on ISPConfig.

I figured out an easy way to move all emails from cpanel to ISPConfig email mailbox. I hope this helps others. It may be useful to move between many other control panels as long as both panels use roundcube webmail.
Please note that below instructions are for transferring contact@domain.com, it could be anything in your case.

Find email folder in your cpanel file manager, e.g. it was home/mail folder on my VPS
Find email folder you want to transfer e.g. home/mail/domain.com/contact for contact@domain.com
Right click the folder, select Compress, create zip file
Download the file to your PC.
Connect to your new ISPConfig server with FTP account of domain.com or any other website on the server
Connect to your new server with SSH, Go to root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir#
Run below commands, I think I don't need to understand each command as this should be done by experienced hands only.

root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir# mv /var/www/domain.com/web/contact.zip .
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir# unzip contact.zip
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir# mv hr/* .
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir# cd cur
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir/cur# mv -v ../hr/cur/* .
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir/cur# cd ..
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir# chown -R vmail:vmail .
root@servername:/var/vmail/domain.com/contact/Maildir# rm contact.zip

